# Get the max, min value and the respective owner of that max, min price - Pandas

Tags: pandas

I have this df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'code_1':[123,456,789,456,123],
                   'code_2':[333,666,999,666,333],
                   'seller':['Andres','Mike','Paul','Andy','Mike'],
                   'price':[12.2,23.51,12.34,10.2,13.0]})
```

and I want to get this as output:

```
dff = pd.DataFrame({'code_1':[123,456,789],
                    'code_2':[333,666,999],
                   'seller_maxprice':['Mike','Mike','Paul'],
                   'max_price':[13,23.51,12.34],
                    'avg_price':[12.6,16.85,12.34],
                   'seller_mainprice':['Andres','Andy','Paul'],
                   'min_price':[12.2,10.20,12.34]})
```

So, from DF I want to get the `maxprice, minprice, avgprice, sellermaxprice and sellerminprice` of `cod_1 and/or cod_2`

And there´s one more issue:  I dont have both unique indentifier: `cod_1` and `cod_2` all the time. Sometimes I Have `cod_1 and cod_2 is null` and vice-versa

I tried:

```
result = df.groupby(['code_1']).agg({'price': ['mean', 'min', 'max']})
```

But this approach has two issues:

**1: will fail when `code_1` is `null`**

**2: Does not shoe the seller max and seller min_price**

an anyone help me with this?

Comment: What result do you expect when `code_1` is `null` @StatsPy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is the right one, we can improve it in a number of small ways:

- If you set `seller` as the index, then your seller min/maxprice become `idxmin` and `idxmax` − it’s OK for the index to be non-unique
- If you expect `code_1` to be `null`, you can use `fillna` to add some placeholder values
- If you use `['price']` after `.groupby` you’ll get a SeriesGroupBy instead of a DataFrameGroupBy which means you don’t have to specify which columns to aggregate in `.agg()`
- You can define the column names as keys in `.agg()`

```
>>> df.set_index('seller').fillna({'code_1': 'missing'})\
...   .groupby(['code_1', 'code_2'])['price']\
...   .agg(maxprice='max', minprice='min', aver_price='mean',
...        seller_minprice='idxmin', seller_maxprice='idxmax',
...       ).reset_index()
...
   code_1  code_2  maxprice  minprice  aver_price seller_minprice seller_maxprice
0     123     333     13.00     12.20      12.600          Andres            Mike
1     456     666     23.51     10.20      16.855            Andy            Mike
2     789     999     12.34     12.34      12.340            Paul            Paul
```

Comment: @BENY, Cimbali, both approachs worked just fine.  I choose Cimbali's answer because it took 33 seconds to execute while BENY's took 3minutes ans 28seconds.  Thanks to both of youy guys.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with `groupby` and `apply`

```
dff = df.groupby(['code_1','code_2']).apply(lambda x : pd.Series({'seller_maxprice':x.loc[x['price'].idxmax(),'seller'],
                                                            'max_price':x['price'].max(),
                                                            'seller_minprice': x.loc[x['price'].idxmin(), 'seller'],
                                                            'min_price': x['price'].min(),
                                                            'aver_price':x['price'].mean()
                                                            })).reset_index()
Out[22]: 
   code_1  code_2 seller_maxprice  ...  seller_minprice min_price  aver_price
0     123     333            Mike  ...           Andres     12.20      12.600
1     456     666            Mike  ...             Andy     10.20      16.855
2     789     999            Paul  ...             Paul     12.34      12.340
[3 rows x 7 columns]
```

Comment: thanks man, helped me a lot.